# Do we need to explicitly close Streams or Readers passed as anonymous classes in method parameters?

Tags: java, java-7

```
transformer = factory.newTransformer(new StreamSource(xslReader));
```

Also, is there a need to explicitly close Reader and Writer classes at all ? What if there was a InputStream passed here in place of StreamSource like
`BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStream("file.txt"));`

Comment: It's up to the method being called. Have you considered consulting its Javadoc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you generally don't need to close something that got passed into your method as parameter, unless you bound by contract to do so.

Whoever obtained an instance of `Closeable` can most likely handle closing it as well.

And yes, you should close things that declared as `Closeable`, and that you yourself instantiated, to prevent resource leaks. Closeable wrappers (readers, writers, buffers, etc.) close their underlying data sources when they themselves are closed, so in your (modified) example

```
var breader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("myFile")))
breader.close();
```

Closing the `breader` will cascade close operation, closing the `BufferedReader` first, then `InputStreamReader`, and finally the `FileInputStream`, releasing file descriptors and notifying your operating system that you finished working with that file.